# CSS Menu - how to

Tags: html, css

hello i have a simple menu nothing impressive :)
simple up to bottom now my question is
i want to make like a triple menu at the bottom of my menu to look nice
something like this:

```
|   | (space) |       | (space) |   |
```

the first and last one have same size while the middle one is a little wider now i want to ask what is the best way to make it do i just use 3 divs? or a table maybe? note that i want them to have each theyre own border I just want to make them apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create a menu like that, is you better use the `<ul>` for the parent and `<li>` tags. Keep fixed width for both the first and last and then give some margin for them. Check the below snippet:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-size: 10pt;}

footer {text-align: center;}
footer ul {display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #99f; padding: 5px; margin: 15px;}
footer ul li {display: inline-block; width: 300px;}
footer ul li:first-child,
footer ul li:last-child {width: 100px; display: inline-block;}
footer ul li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #999; color: #333; margin: 5px; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Small #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Longest Item As You Wanted</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Small #2</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple menu here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use unordered lists (ul) tag to displayed simple footer menu like below structure:

HTML code:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
ul li {padding: 5 10px;}
ul li:first-child{padding-left:0;}
ul li:last-child{padding-right:0;}
```